# Powershell MSAL - How to get Authority/Endpoint Property from Get-MsalToken

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-powershell

I am able to successfully retrieve a token for Sharepoint Online using Powershell MSAL 4.37.0 and a ClientCertificate.  What I have not been able to successfully do is pass in an Authority.  When I pass Authority as a parameter to either New-MsalClientApplication/Get-MsalClientApplication or to Get-MsalToken it just seems to ignore that parameter.  Get-MsalToken still runs successfully, but I cannot determine what it is using as its endpoint.

I am using Powershell to test the functionality and my set-up since I cannot seem to get it working with NODE.js and I continue to have problems with the Authority.  Since it works successfully with Powershell, it seems all of my other config is set up correctly, I just need to verify the authority.  I have authority set up as $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + $tenantID + '/oauth2/v2.0/token'.

```
$certStorePath  = "cert:\LocalMachine\TrustedPublisher";

$certDetails = Get-ChildItem -Path $certStorePath | Where {$_.Issuer -like "*selfsigned*"}   
$thumbPrint = $certDetails.Thumbprint;

$ClientCertificate = Get-Item "Cert:\LocalMachine\TrustedPublisher\$($thumbPrint)";
$ClientCertificate.GetType();


$MsalClientApplication = New-MsalClientApplication -ClientId $appID -ClientCertificate $ClientCertificate -TenantId $tenant;

try
{

    $msalToken = $MsalClientApplication | Get-MsalToken -Authority $authority -Scope $scope;



    $msalToken.AccessToken | Get-JWTDetails;
}

catch
{
    Write-Host $_.Exception | format-list -force
}
```

Any ideas on how I can either get the -Authority parameter to work (and thus either succeed or fail as I change the Authority value) or return the Authority as a property from the token so that I can verify what Authority is correct?

Thanks, Clint

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on how I can either get the -Authority parameter to work (and thus either succeed or fail as I change the Authority value) or return the Authority as a property from the token so that I can verify what Authority is correct?

To check or get the authority and verify whether the authority is correct, check the below:

For sample, I generated access token by passing the `TenantID`:

*As a workaround, you can pass the `TenantID` while generating the access token*

```
$msalToken = Get-MsalToken -ClientId 'ClientID' -ClientSecret (ConvertTo-SecureString 'ClientSecret' -AsPlainText -Force) -TenantId 'TenantID' -Scope 'https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/.default'

$msalToken
```

[image]

Now to check the authority, you can **decode the access token** by using the below function:

```
function Parse-JWTtoken {
 
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$token)
 
    #Validate as per https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519
    #Access and ID tokens are fine, Refresh tokens will not work
    if (!$token.Contains(".") -or !$token.StartsWith("eyJ")) { Write-Error "Invalid token" -ErrorAction Stop }
 
    #Header
    $tokenheader = $token.Split(".")[0].Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/')
    #Fix padding as needed, keep adding "=" until string length modulus 4 reaches 0
    while ($tokenheader.Length % 4) { Write-Verbose "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string, adding ="; $tokenheader += "=" }
    Write-Verbose "Base64 encoded (padded) header:"
    Write-Verbose $tokenheader
    #Convert from Base64 encoded string to PSObject all at once
    Write-Verbose "Decoded header:"
    [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([system.convert]::FromBase64String($tokenheader)) | ConvertFrom-Json | fl | Out-Default
 
    #Payload
    $tokenPayload = $token.Split(".")[1].Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/')
    #Fix padding as needed, keep adding "=" until string length modulus 4 reaches 0
    while ($tokenPayload.Length % 4) { Write-Verbose "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string, adding ="; $tokenPayload += "=" }
    Write-Verbose "Base64 encoded (padded) payoad:"
    Write-Verbose $tokenPayload
    #Convert to Byte array
    $tokenByteArray = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($tokenPayload)
    #Convert to string array
    $tokenArray = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($tokenByteArray)
    Write-Verbose "Decoded array in JSON format:"
    Write-Verbose $tokenArray
    #Convert from JSON to PSObject
    $tokobj = $tokenArray | ConvertFrom-Json
    Write-Verbose "Decoded Payload:"
    
    return $tokobj
}
```

[image]

Now decode the access token as below and check the **`iss`** claim to check the authority:

[image]

**If still the issue persists**, check the below:

[PowerShell Gallery | Get-MsalToken.ps1 4.2.1.1](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MSAL.PS/4.2.1.1/Content/Get-MsalToken.ps1)